# React - sinon testing - getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon

I want to test if the function destructures the given arguments properly.
The function is:

```
function testFunc(...args) {
  const [nameOfClass, itemName] = args;

  return <div className={nameOfClass}>{itemName}</div>
}
```

I am using mocha, chai and sinon to test if arguments provided to that function are properly destructured. However the test give me "AssertionError: expected false to be true":

```
const funcArguments = ['testClass', 'testItemName'];
const spy = sinon.spy();
testFunc(...funcArguments, spy);
expect(spy.calledWithExactly('testClass', 'testItemName')).to.be.true
```

Is it the fault of destructuring?

Comment: That function doesn't make sense. `...args` is a _rest_ argument, so will inevitably be an array. Arrays don't have the properties you then try to destructure out of it. It also don't seem to fall either of its arguments, so it's not clear why you'd pass a spy.

Comment: True, corrected. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Why do you think that test would pass? The function doesn't do _anything_ with its third argument, certainly not call it with the other two. Are you trying to test that testFunc itself is called with two arguments (and if so, _why_, given that it's the job of the test to call the function not the job of the function to have been called)?

Comment: The third argument is a `spy` - it does not count as argument when using sinon.spy()

Comment: You didn't call the spy.

Comment: @slideshowp2 true, that might be the reason. I tried to call it with `sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy)` but it gives me an error that spy has been called 0 times

Comment: @slideshowp2 thanks a lot for inspiration - you made me thinking and I managed to get the test passing

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the input in the comments, I adjusted the test code to actually call the spy. It looks like it now and it gives the proper result:

```
const funcArguments = ['testClass', 'testItemName'];
const spiedTestFunc = sinon.spy(testFunc);
spiedTestFunc(...funcArguments);
expect(spiedTestFunc.calledWithExactly('testClass', 'testItemName')).to.be.true
```

Comment: That test is totally pointless. Of course the spy is called, you literally just called it. You're only testing the test double.

Comment: I'm learning how to test. I am not able yet to distinguish how to do it properly. The above code is the result of following one tutorial about sinon spy where they gave similar example. But your comment is good lesson for me to watch out for what I'm learning.